# 2D tensor multiplication with its transpose - shouldn't it return a symmetric 2D tesnor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am multiplying a large 2D tensor with its transpose. I am expecting that I would get a symmetric matrix. Here is the sample code.

```
import torch

n = torch.randn(200, 385)
s = n @ n.T
print(torch.allclose(s, s.T))
```

This prints `False`.

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Reproducible. The behavior/result differs when using cuda. Looks bug-ish.

Comment: Suggest raising on pytorch github page.

Comment: Thank you. I did raise this in the PyTorch discussion forum? Is that the place or should I raise somewhere else?